Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade, warning old pc
I'm new here on the forum.
Old PC MBR, no UEFI.
The title is telling but the forum doesn't seem to have a clue what's going on.
I have run into all kinds of trouble due to old PC with MBR.
Ubuntu seems to have missed telling everyone with an old PC that has MBR.
Unlucky I didn't find below before my attempt.
Quote found online:
"Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Installation."
Before using UEFI, the disk partition style must be set to GPT.
When trying to upgrade.... Catastrophe PC dead....
22.04 has grub
24.04 has grub2
They don't work well together, hence black screen with only memtest to choose.
I tried Boot-Repair several times, but it crashed.
I restored to 22.04.5 LTS, all och.
Waiting for response from Ubuntu, nothing yet.

Grub2 has been standard since about 2010 back in BIOS only days. If system is that old, you need lighter weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors) About 2010 with BIOS only system I did convert to using gpt with Ubuntu, but had to have a bios_grub partition for grub to install. Can you run Boot-Repair's summary report & post link in question above?

The decision of UEFI or BIOS installation is made by how the live media is booted. So if you have old hardware that doesn't support UEFI it will make a BIOS install. (At least up to 22.04 but the (desktop) installer has changed for 24.04 but I would imagine it is the same.) I would also imagine the same criteria applies for a upgrade. Also, during a upgrade of Grub it should make a complete update. Did it install a UEFI partition on the MBR disk?

Hi oldfred
Your question about Lightweight flavors:
I have 1 Lubuntu,
3 Xubuntu,
5 Ubuntu
Do you want a Bootrepair from a working system?
which system,
// M@ts

Hi david
your question UEFI partition on the MBR : Sorry can't remember it, but when I look at "Disks" today there is an empty 1GB of unallocated space.
// M@ts

FYI:  This is a Ubuntu Q&A site, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums if you want a Forum (Q&A differs slightly to forums). All releases of Ubuntu Desktop (inc. flavors) will install on legacy disks, the oldest device I use in QA is from 2005 & I concentrate on older hardware, but your question makes little sense to me sorry... If options in the installer aren't letting you do what you want, use Manual Partitioning and tell it what you want, or prepare partitions before starting installer & just select & tell the installer to use partitions you want.

Hi I just want to warn anyone with an old pc to upgrade.
Apologize and withdraw.
Thanks for all the answers and questions.
// M@ts

Try the following:
Start a live Ubuntu session.
After the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gparted
sudo gparted

From Gparted:
Select the hard drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new gpt partition table.
(if there were previous partitions and a previous partition table, delete them from the last to the first)
Create a 500 meg partition, fat32, boot-efi
Create a 50 gig partition, ext4
Create an 8 gig partition, linux swap
Create a partition of the rest of the gigs, ext4
Apply the changes.
Close Gparted.
Close the terminal.
Start the installation.
When you get to partitioning, choose manual / custom.
Grub on the hard drive is usually selected without operator intervention.
The 50-gig partition is mounted as /
The 8-gig partition should already be selected for /swap
The remaining 10-gig partition is mounted as /home
Accept and finish the installation.

You should probably backup all your data first. It is possible to convert an MBR disk to a GPT one without loosing data using 'gdisk'

While I highly recommend gpt, it is not required unless drive over 2TB or dual booting with Windows in UEFI mode. But only place MBR still required is BIOS boot of a Windows install. Conversion may erase drive, so good backups required. And you need either bios_grub or ESP and reinstall of grub after conversion.

Hi
My partitioning right now.
40 GB/,
No swap, later I will put it back on the disk.
74 GB /home 87% full
On a 128 GB SSD
Just now my neighbor called, Have you noticed that our fiber is down, YES YES YES YES
Any problem with our connection box will be fixed later. ?? date ??
Run a computer via the mobile, and have a few MB left need to expand. Little problem to answer questions quickly.
// M@ts

Hi oldfred
I was going to try another one
1GB boot Fat32
40 GB Btrfs /
74 GB ext4, 7 years old home
Just haven't had time
// M@ts
